# ¿Línea de tiempo en eje X en un chart en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de hacer una gráfica que en el eje X tenga una línea de tiempo con intervalo de 1 hora y en eje Y un número flotante.
Pero al momento de ejecutarlo, sin tener ningún punto me aparece así:

[image: Grafica]

Quiero que aunque no tenga puntos aparezca la línea de tiempo y los límites del eje Y también.
Los límites del eje Y sólo aparecen si introduzco un punto a la gráfica y en el eje X salen puros 00:00

[image: Gráfica con un punto]

El punto que agrego no se ve porque no está entre los valores del eje X, por lo mismo de que sólo muestra 00:00.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            chartGrease.ChartAreas["GreaseChartArea"].AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chartGrease.ChartAreas["GreaseChartArea"].AxisX.Minimum = 14;
            chartGrease.ChartAreas["GreaseChartArea"].AxisX.Maximum = 21.5;
            chartGrease.ChartAreas["GreaseChartArea"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chartGrease.ChartAreas["GreaseChartArea"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";

            chartGrease.Series["Grasa"].Points.AddXY(new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 16, 0, 0), 1.5);
```

Los límites del eje Y los pongo directamente en las propiedades, los del eje X son los únicos que los pongo por código, por ser de tipo `Time`

Comment: podes aclarar que tipo de control es el chart?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Chart.